# htop always show one cpu usage full

Tags: centos, top, cpu-usage, htop

I have a server with two cpus (24 core * 2), recently, I noted that `htop` always report one cpu is fully usage
[image]

But I cant find any threads with highly cpu usage by `htop`, `top` or `ps -ef`

I have tried:

reboot system

update `htop`

My system is:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)

uname -a
Linux server 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 4 20:48:51 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## update

To put it simply, I first encountered this problem, that is, htop showed that half of the CPU was occupied, but other commands such as top and ps were inconsistent with this. At first, I thought it was htop's fault.

After I posted this problem, I came up with a simple method. I checked the power of the server through out-of-band management, and I found that the total power was very large, close to 300W, which was consistent with a cpu running at full speed when the server had no other load.

Then I suspected that some hidden processes used CPU and checked this through the unhide tool (http://github.com/YJesus/Unhide).

unhide list a lot of hide process, that not showing in `top` and `htop`
[image]

after search in `Google`, I think its beacuse of a kind of `crypto mining malware`

After kill all of this, the CPU usage in `htop` is ok, but after reboot this hide process run again

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150311/discussion-on-question-by-zhang-htop-always-show-one-cpu-usage-full); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.